# Scan a file in realtime and execute certain commands on encountering 5 consecutive identical lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, monitoring

Mysql log has something like:

```
1649560 Query select * from actions where uniqueid like 'ernie-1328697839.1233158-%-dequeue' and class='queue' and server='ernie' and time<='1328698322' and action='dequeue' limit 1
1649560 Query select * from actions where uniqueid like 'ernie-1328697839.1233158-%-dequeue' and class='queue' and server='ernie' and time<='1328698322' and action='dequeue' limit 1
1649560 Query select * from actions where uniqueid like 'ernie-1328697839.1233158-%-dequeue' and class='queue' and server='ernie' and time<='1328698322' and action='dequeue' limit 1
1649560 Query select * from actions where uniqueid like 'ernie-1328697839.1233158-%-dequeue' and class='queue' and server='ernie' and time<='1328698322' and action='dequeue' limit 1
1649560 Query select * from actions where uniqueid like 'ernie-1328697839.1233158-%-dequeue' and class='queue' and server='ernie' and time<='1328698322' and action='dequeue' limit 1
1649560 Query select * from actions where uniqueid like 'ernie-1328697839.1233158-%-dequeue' and class='queue' and server='ernie' and time<='1328698322' and action='dequeue' limit 1
1649560 Query select * from actions where uniqueid like 'ernie-1328697839.1233158-%-dequeue' and class='queue' and server='ernie' and time<='1328698322' and action='dequeue' limit 1
1649560 Query select * from actions where uniqueid like 'ernie-1328697839.1233158-%-dequeue' and class='queue' and server='ernie' and time<='1328698322' and action='dequeue' limit 1
```

I want a bash shell script that will do the follwoing:

1. The script will scan the `mysql.log` file in real time (something like `tail -F mysql.log`)
2. If it encounters 5 consecutive identical lines then it would invoke some commands (say `echo "yes"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 awk '$0 != l { l=$0; c=0 }
      l=$0 {c++; if (c>=5) {system("YOURCOMMAND HERE")}}' LOGFILE
```

can do it for you... but what you mean by real time? If it had to be run constantly, set up some `fifo` mechanism for it, or something like that. Or simply do:

```
 tail -F LOGFILE | <THEABOVE_AWK_SCRIPT>
```

Comment: by realtime i meant the script will run constantly and scan the mysql.log(something like tail -f mysql.log|while readline )

Comment: Thanks..:) better to use "tail -F"

Comment: +1 -- not strictly necessary to declare the variables, so you could drop the BEGIN block altogether

Comment: @glenn jackmann                                                     `tail -F LOGFILE|awk '$0 != l { l=$0; c=0 }
      l=$0 {c++; if (c>=5) {system("YOURCOMMAND HERE")}}'`

Comment: @Zsolt Botykai Now i want to send alert mail on encountering 5 consecutive identical lines. So the script will be like:  `tail -F mysql.log|awk '$0 != l { l=$0; c=0 } l=$0 {c++; if (c>=5) {system("echo Alert|mail -s Alert")}}'`  Now for a large number of consecutive identical lines the above script will continue on sending mail.  I want the script to send a mail and wait for 5 mins...and even after 5 mins if it encounters the same criterion then again it would send an alert mail. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @user973430 that can't be solved easily from an `awk` script. e.g. you can put another `system` command after the mail alert, like: `tail -F mysql.log|awk '$0 != l { l=$0; c=0 } l=$0 {c++; if (c>=5) {system("echo Alert|mail -s Alert") ; system("sleep 5m")}}'`. But with it the script sleeps, and reads the file from where it had finished...

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai I want the script to continue scanning...I want the script to send a mail and wait for 5 mins...and even after 5 mins if it encounters the same criterion then again it would send an alert mail. Something like:  `touch -d '-5 minute' limit;
if [ limit -nt last_notification ]; then
echo "Alert"|mailx -s "Error" user@domain;
touch last_notification;fi`

Comment: OK, but that does not handles the seeking to the logfile. I mean, you are scanning your logs, and in the middle of it the script finds the repetition, sends the mail, than waits 5 minutes, then restart from the same point (in the log file) as it had sent the mail? Well the above one with the `sleep` does that. *BUT* I can't guarantee that it will work correctly: under 5 minutes a lot of lines can get into that pipe...

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai Is there any way to incorporate `touch -d '-5 minute' limit; if [ limit -nt last_notification ]; then echo "Alert"|mailx -s "Error" user@domain; touch last_notification;fi` in the awk

Comment: Yes. Write that to a shell script, and invoke that with `system("your_Script.sh")`.